# Preallocating in MATLAB when a loop has the "Union" function

Tags: matlab

Assume there is a loop which should be preallocated. It can be done either by **"zeros"**, **"eye"** or **"NAN"** matrices. The problem is when one of these 3 matrices are being used, after using **union** function, an extra line of zeros (or one or NAN) will be remain which should delete at the end.

For example:

```
Q=[0 0];

for i=1:10
q=  [rand(1) 2*rand(1)];
Q= union(Q,q,'rows');
end
```

Consequently, there is a **[0 0]** array remain at the beginning of our matrix which should be deleted.

`Q(1,:)=[];`

I was wondering if you could help with a code which can do reallocating without needing erasing the first line.

P.S. just image there is a reason for keep the union and loop.

Thanks

Comment: @Divakar Would you kindly take a look at this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ask for a union that you don't want:

```
Q = [];

for i=1:10
    q = [rand(1) 2*rand(1)];
    if(isempty(Q))
        Q = q;
    else
        Q = union(Q,q,'rows');
    end
end
```

Or, instead of initializing Q with values that you don't want, initialize it with a value you DO want:

```
Q = [rand(1) 2*rand(1)];

for i=1:9
    q = [rand(1) 2*rand(1)];
    Q = union(Q,q,'rows');
end
```

This really has nothing to do with preallocation.  The way `union` works forces it to return a new value for Q each time, which means you overwrite the previous value.  `preallocation` is when you insert data into the correct location of an appropriately-sized output matrix, in order to avoid extra memory allocations due to resizing your output.